# Convert a String in Java to a VARCHAR IN SQL

Tags: java, sql, database, plsql

I am trying to write PL/SQL in Java.
I want to pass an argument as String, but in the SQL Procedure it is a VARCHAR(140).
However it is giving me an error when I run the program and I don't understand why?

This is my SQL PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE task1
 (input_tweet_id IN integer, input_user_id IN integer, input_time IN timestamp, input_tweet IN varchar(140))
is
begin
    INSERT INTO tweet(tweetid, userid, publishtime, tweet)
    VALUES (input_tweet_id,input_user_id,input_time,input_tweet);
END;
```

The Java call:

```
    int in_tweet_id = 0;
    int in_user_id = 0;
    Timestamp in_time =null;
    String in_tweet ="";

 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (connStr, uname, passwd);
 CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call task1(?, ?)}");
       // cstmt.registerOutParameter (1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cstmt.setInt(1, in_tweet_id);
        cstmt.setInt(2, in_user_id);
        cstmt.setTimestamp(3,in_time);
        cstmt.setString(4,in_tweet);
```

The error:

```
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:197)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:269)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:490)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5013)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setString(OracleCallableStatement.java:4094)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:246)
        at hw4.execute_task1(hw4.java:247)
        at hw4.main(hw4.java:101)
```

Comment: You luckily removed the exception message from the stacktrace, because it could be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to set the 3rd & 4th `CallableStatement` parameters where there are only 2 defined

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call task1(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
```

Comment: Yeah I changed that, but does it need to have the "?" in the very front?
{? = call .......} Does that need to be there because i am not returning anything ?

Comment: I changed it to this : CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call task1(?,?,?,?)}");

Comment: No need, take a look at [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/)

Comment: And I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object USER.TASK1 is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Can you check the type being sent to column 7 with the type that's being sent in? Looks like a mismatch...

Comment: (input_tweet_id IN integer, input_user_id IN integer, input_time IN timestamp, input_tweet IN varchar(140))
This is what i have on the sql. I don't know which is column 7. Do they count the keyword IN?

Comment: `in_time` is still `null` so you need to call `cstmt.setNull(3,TYPES.NULL)` to set it